# ConTeXt: \setupframedtexts[name][..=..] not using "name" argument (beginner)

Tags: context, framed

I am learning ConTeXt (and so far it is a great experience!); however, while making notes and tests with "ConTeXt: An Excursion," and occasionally looking to into reference manual, I have hit into following:

Command `\setupframedtexts`should work as follows: `\setupframedtexts[name][..=..]` (according to reference manual), but it ignores the `name` (and if `name` is provided it results to defaults).

Or am I making syntactical error somewhere?

MWE:

```
\setupframedtexts[myFrame][frame=off,topframe=on,bottomframe=on,width=\textwidth]

\starttext

\startframedtext[myFrame]
\input Knuth
\stopframedtext

\stoptext
```

I also want to use ConTeXt setups like so:

```
\setupsomething[mything]
[settings]

\setupsomethingelse[myanotherthing]
[settings,
setting={\something[mything]}]
```

For example:

```
\setupframedtexts[mySectionFrame]
[frame=off,
topframe=on,
bottomframe=on,
width=\textwidth]

\definehead[mySection][section]
\setuphead[mySection]
[numberstyle=bold,
 textstyle=bold,
 before=\vskip 2\baselineskip{\startframedtext[mySectionFrame]}
 after=\stopframedtext\vskip\baselineskip]
```

My question originated from this situation.

This might be considered as two questions in one, but they are (pretty much) related, so I hoope it doesnt mind.

**Final note:** I know, that reference manual is not perfectly up-to-date, but behaviour that would accept named argument (to me) makes more sense.

Comment: ```\defineframedtext[myFrame]
\setupframedtext[myFrame][frame=off,topframe=on,bottomframe=on,width=\textwidth]
\starttext
\startmyFrame
\input Knuth
\stopmyFrame
\stoptext``` You have to define your framed text first.

Comment: Additionally, your setup points to *two* or more environments. `\setupframedtext`, in singular, is enough. A functional example: ```\defineframedtext[myFrame]
\setupframedtext[myFrame][frame=off,topframe=on,bottomframe=on,width=\textwidth]
\definehead[mySection][section]
\setuphead[mySection]
[numberstyle=\bf,
textstyle=\bf,
before={\vskip 2\baselineskip \startmyFrame},
after={\stopmyFrame\vskip\baselineskip}]
\starttext
\startmyFrame
\input Knuth
\stopmyFrame
\startmySection 
\input zapf
\stopmySection 
\stoptext```

Comment: @Noone Thank you for clarification. Would you like to make it an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your MWE didn't work because you're passing `myFramed` as a parameter to `\startframedtext ... \stopframedtext` and it will be ignored.

In ConTeXt usually a `\setup...` has a `\define...` counterpart. In your case, you need to define your `framedtext` first via `\defineframedtext[myFrame]`, so you set it up later. Notice `\setupframedtext[myFrame]`, in singular. The plural form applies changes to framed texts overall, although you could just use it specifying `myFramed`, what you apparently tried. `\defineframedtext[myFrame]` will define `\startmyFrame` and `\stopmyFrame`. Let's see:

```
\defineframedtext[myFrame]
\setupframedtext[myFrame][frame=off,topframe=on,bottomframe=on,width=\textwidth] 
\starttext
\startmyFrame
\input Knuth
\stopmyFrame
\stoptext
```

Now your environment is ready to be used in a section head (when `bold` doesn't do anything, try `\bf` instead). I suggest you to enclose macros with braces when your content after `before=` and `after=` is formed by "complex" macros to avoid funny parsing errors.

```
\defineframedtext[myFrame]
\setupframedtext[myFrame][frame=off,topframe=on,bottomframe=on,width=\textwidth]
\definehead[mySection][section]
\setuphead[mySection] [numberstyle=\bf, textstyle=\bf, before={\vskip 2\baselineskip \startmyFrame}, after={\stopmyFrame\vskip\baselineskip}]
\starttext
\startmyFrame
\input Knuth
\stopmyFrame
\startmySection
\input zapf
\stopmySection
\stoptext
```

[ConTeXt command list](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/qrcs/setup-en.pdf) is quite illustrative in case you want to understand better the endless amount of `\setup`s and `\define`s which ConTeXt handles with.